# Codeigniter (controller)file path in javascript file

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

This is how the directory structure looks like in my codeigniter installation.

```
Root
-www
-lib
--application
--assets
---js
```

I am looking to get path of a controller in the javascript file located at js folder. How can I do that ?

Edit: I need the path to the php script for an Ajax call.

Comment: Using JS? or using PHP? When you say get, what do you mean?

Comment: i guess in order to obtain the right answer.. we would need to know why do you need this? do you need the full absolute path? by knowing this we might give you a better answer

Comment: @CodeGodie Yes, I think you are right. I have updated the original.

Comment: if it is for ajax, then you dont need the absolute file path. you need the URL which you can do with `base_url("controller/method")` like @Rejoanul suggested. Have you tried that?

Comment: if ajax then use `site_url()` instead of `base_url()`. does not need link main controller just use `site_url('controller/method')` it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get corresponding controller name by using `$this->router->fetch_class()`

make a hidden field in your html file

```
<input type="hidden" id="con_path" value="<?php echo base_url('application/controllers').'/'.$this->router->fetch_class();?>"/>
```

then grab it in your JS file

```
var con_path = $('#con_path').val();
```

Comment: base_url will not give you the file path

Comment: so what about this? `<input type="hidden" id="con_path" value="<?php echo base_url('application/controllers').'/'.ucfirst($this->router->fetch_class()).'.php';?>"/>
`

Comment: depends on why he wants to use it.. he probably needs the absolute file path rather than the url